# An upper bound for $ \min _{\sigma \in S(k)}\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left|w_{\sigma(j)}-v_{j}\right|\right\}$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Let $w_j, v_j \geq 0$ satisfying $\sum_{j=1}^{k} w_j = \sum_{j=1}^{k} v_j = 1$. Are we able to find an upper bound for
$$
\min _{\sigma \in S(k)}\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{k}\left|w_{\sigma(j)}-v_{j}\right|\right\},
$$
where $S(k)$ denotes the set of all permutations?

My guess is that an upper bound is 2 and my intuition would be as follows (not rigorous):

Since we are taking the minimum of all permutations, then if there is a maxima, we must have that $w_1 = \cdots = w_k = 1/k$. In this case $v_1 = 1, v_2=\cdots=v_k=0$ would yield the maximum of the expression, which is $2-2/k$.

Comment: How about $\sum_{j=1}^k |w_j - v_j| \le \sum_{j=1}^k (w_j + v_j) = 2$?